# L2-Bounded Martingales

Tags: probability, martingales

A martingale $\{u_n\}$ is $\mathcal{L}^2-bounded$.
Show that:
$$
\lim \int (u-u_n)^2 d\mu = 0
$$

$$
\int (u_{j+k} -u_j)^2 d\mu
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& = \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \int (u_l-u_{l-1})^2 d\mu
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, since it's positive and measurable:
$$
\int \liminf(u-u_n)^2 d\mu
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& \leq \liminf \int (u-u_n)^2 d\mu \\
& \leq \limsup \int (u-u_n)^2 d\mu \\
& \leq \limsup\sum_{l= n+1}^{\infty} \int (u_l-u_{l-1})^2 d\mu \\
& = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

The book reasoned that zero due to the $\mathcal{L}^2$-boundedness of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int (u_k-u_{k-1})^2 d\mu <\infty$.

Could someone explain me **why the last result is zero?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should read $$
\int \liminf(u-u_n)^2 d\mu
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& \leq \liminf \int (u-u_n)^2 d\mu \\
& \leq \limsup \int (u-u_n)^2 d\mu \\
& \leq \limsup\sum_{l=n+1}^{\infty} \int (u_l-u_{l-1})^2 d\mu \\
& = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
It is an elementary fact that if $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum a_n <\infty$ then $\sum_{l=n+1}^{\infty} a_l \to 0$.

Comment: But does it holds even with the square, as in this case? So if $a^2_n \geq 0$ and $\sum a^2_n < \infty$ then $\sum^{\infty} a^2_ l \longmapsto 0$ ?

Comment: What is  the difference? It is just a question of renaming $a_l^{2}$ as your new $a_l$. @GabrielePillitteri